# I'm using xampp for local server and I want to test my locally hosted site to android mobile. How would I do that

Tags: android, responsive-design, xampp

I'm using xampp for local server in a 64-bit system. I want to test my locally hosted site to android mobile device to check the responsiveness without hosting it to any web server. How would I do that. Please answer soon

Comment: you mean loading it on your android device while it's on the same network?  or publicly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Apache module in XAMPP is started up and your android phone is connected to your router(assuming that you are on a wireless network). Find the local IP address of the computer hosting the server. Mine, for example, is 192.168.1.142. This may or may not be similar to yours.  Type that IP address into the phone's URL bar. You may need to append the port number to that too, depending on the server settings. For example, if XAMPP is running Apache on port 8080: 192.168.1.142:8080.

To obtain your local IP, it slightly varies depending on the Operating system.

For windows, go to command prompt and do the command `ipconfig`, it should appear as an entry there.

For linux-based systems, I believe you use the command `ifconfig` in terminal.

If you do not have a wireless access point, it may not be possible to visit it as the phone naturally does not have an ethernet port.

Comment: That's great! Do you mind if you mark my entry as the answer so this question is marked solved?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not possible. However you could find a free web host to try that out. Here is one:
http://www.host-ed.net

If you really don't want to use a web host, then try downloading the files to your phone/tablet and running them directly from phone/tablet. That will work if you have just plain html/php files. Otherwise browse google play to find a app that can run those files.